# HornetQ - how to send and convert POJO

Tags: jackson, gson, pojo, hornetq

I'm using HornetQ in embedded mode.

I'm trying to send from Publisher to Consumer a POJO object:

```
public class Pojo implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String  name;
    private String  phone;

    // constructors, getters & setters
}
```

My idea is to convert the POJO to a Map and send each properties via ClientMessage. (In this way, the Consumer will be able to filter messages by POJO's properties)

To achieve this, I'm using Jackson ObjectMapper.

#### Publisher

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> pojoMap = mapper.convertValue(new Pojo(13, "name", "phone"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
pojoMap.forEach(message::putObjectProperty);
producer.send(message);
```

#### Consumer

```
consumer.setMessageHandler(message -> {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    Pojo pojo = mapper.convertValue(mapJson, Pojo.class);
});
```

The problem is that during deserializing (in Consumer) ObjectMapper throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.lang.String' out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: org.hornetq.core.example.Pojo["phone"])
...
```

From what I understood, ObjectMapper is looking for 'phone' value and wants a String, but it finds an Object and crashes.

How can I solve this problem?

Are there alternatives?

I also tried to use Gson instead of Jackson, but it returns me the same error.

The funny fact is that if you send an object which doesn't have any String parameters, it works without any problems.

(Shouldn't be necessary, but if you want) Here you can find the entire classes of:

- Server https://pastebin.com/kjPQU1Cc
- Pojo https://pastebin.com/kCkkWiwn
- Publisher https://pastebin.com/c1CkSyMM
- Consumer https://pastebin.com/G2f5YxCs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really obvious, but Jackson fails while deserializing `org.hornetq.api.core.SimpleString` that Jackson is not aware of.
The same goes to Gson, since `SimpleString` is not a standard class.

You have two options here:

- Either normalize the incoming message payload to standard objects.
- Or implement a custom `SimpleString` serializer/deserializer.

#### Option #1: Normalization

By the way, `Message.toMap()` returns message system properties as well (your code in PasteBin seems to use it), so they can collide with your custom object properties (I don't use HornetQ so I can use wrong terms).
I believe, the properties should be normalized like this:

```java
public static Map<String, Object> getNormalizedPropertiesFrom(final Message message) {
    return message.getPropertyNames()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    SimpleString::toString,
                    simpleString -> {
                        final Object objectProperty = message.getObjectProperty(simpleString);
                        if ( objectProperty instanceof SimpleString ) {
                            return objectProperty.toString();
                        }
                        return objectProperty;
                    }
            ));
}
```

This, unlike `Message.toMap()`, will discard system properties like `durable`, `address`, `messageID`, `expiration`, `type`, `priority`, and `timestamp`.
So, what you need here is `mapper.convertValue(getNormalizedPropertiesFrom(message), Pojo.class)`.

#### Option #2: Custom (de)serialization

In this case, you can simplify properties extraction

```java
public static Map<SimpleString, Object> getPropertiesFrom(final Message message) {
    return message.getPropertyNames()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), message::getObjectProperty));
}
```

But your `ObjectMapper` instance must be aware of how `SimpleString` is (de)serialized.
Note that `ObjectMapper.convertValue()` (I believe) uses intermediate objects while converting, it requires a serializer for this scenario (`Message` -> `Map<SimpleString, Object>` via custom serialization -> *some intermediate representation* via built-in deserialization -> `Pojo`).

```java
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                .addSerializer(SimpleString.class, new JsonSerializer<SimpleString>() {
                    @Override
                    public void serialize(@Nonnull final SimpleString simpleString, final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, final SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
                            throws IOException {
                        jsonGenerator.writeString(simpleString.toString());
                    }
                })
        )
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

For performance reasons, you should use single `ObjectMapper` instance.

Both options will produce:

> `Pojo{id=13, name=name, phone=phone}`

for the `Pojo` class,

> `{phone=phone, name=name, id=13}`

for the properties, and something like

> `ClientMessage[messageID=8, durable=false, address=q49589558,userID=null,properties=TypedProperties[id=13,phone=phone,name=name]]`

for the client message.